# iOS Bonjour Device Connection Limit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, bonjour

If I am writing my own networking services via Bonjour (instead of GameKit's implementation), is there any limit to the amount of devices that can connect to a single socket? Meaning, I have one device that is the "host", is there a limit to how many other devices can connect to the host via Bluetooth/Wi-fi?

Comment: this has nothing to do with bonjour. Bonjour provides discovery of services.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of remote users able to connect to the given host is dictated by the max number of file descriptors iOS allows you to open on a socket. It's not strictly a Bonjour issue. I'm unable to find any documentation for iOS but the default value for OS X is presently around 256 open descriptors per socket (low compared to other UNIXes, although it can easily be bumped).

Given the hardware constraints of an iOS device I would assume this max value is lower, but should still be in the hundreds, comfortably enough for gameplay between users on the same link-local network.

Get above that number of concurrent players and the likelihood is that CPU and network conditions would be the limiting factor anyway.